# Vertica fail to execute my query

Tags: vertica

Working on vertica database currently,faced some error,have no idea for the error so need some helps here :)
below are my query and expected output:

```
SELECT 
  country
  , merchant
  , DISTINCT(merchant)
  , COUNT(*) as 'Total Transaction'
  , Max(price) as 'Max_Charge' 
FROM transaction_table
WHERE  ("action")='CHARGE' and action_status='COMPLETED'
GROUP by(msisdn)
```

[my table and expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgXQY.png)

Comment: where is the error message? What is "action"? What is "action_status?

Answer (score 0):

The query does not seem to make a lot of sense, and from what I understood, it has really basic SQL shortcomings, that's why I voted you down. See the explanation below; try to follow the suggestions; and finally edit your question once you've tried something along the lines below.

Looks like going back to the documentation of (any, not just Vertica) SQL could help you a lot:

1. The `DISTINCT` keyword is only "legal" directly after `SELECT` or in `COUNT(DISTINCT <expression>`)
2. In a `GROUP BY` query, the columns in the SELECT list are either columns that will be repeated in the `GROUP BY` clause, or they are aggregate functions - like your MAX() and your COUNT() . `GROUP BY (msisdn)` when `msisdn` is not in the SELECT list won't help at all.

Hope these hints help ---

Good luck

Marco the Sane